# Computed field that displays the full username of the author

Tags: entities

I am using a computed field and I want to display the field_first_name and field_last_name, which are properties of the user that created that node.

I have been trying things, but it seems like $entity does not have a uid?

I have no idea how to get load the user. These are the variables I have:

> The variables available to your code include: &$entity_field,
>   $entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, and $items. To
>   set the value of the field, set $entity_field[0]['value']. For
>   multi-value computed fields continue with $entity_field[1]['value'].
>   Here's a simple example which sets the computed field's value to the
>   value of the sum of the number fields (field_a and field_b) in a node
>   entity: $entity_field[0]['value'] =
>   array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity,
>   'field_a'))) + array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type,
>   $entity, 'field_b'))); The first pop fetches the last (or only) item
>   from the field while the second pop fetches its ['value'] contents
>   (assuming it's the only key that's set).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear what your use case is, but it's possible that the realname module will do exactly what you're after https://www.drupal.org/project/realname

under /admin/config/people/realname enter tokens for the fields you want eg [user:field_profile_first_name] [user:field_profile_last_name] then whenever the username gets printed it will display these fields instead

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
$uid = $entity->uid;  // Grab the author of the node (this is a profile-type node)
$user = user_load($uid);  // Load the user object, based on user id
$first = $user->field_first_name['und']['0']['value'];
$last = $user->field_last_name['und']['0']['value'];

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $first." ".$last;
```